# Modelbinder defaults to 0 when returning null instead of the value set in the controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

I have a custom model binder, being used in a REST API, which looks as follows:

```
public class CustomQueryModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task<ModelBindingResult> BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
      if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bindingContext.ModelName) && bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(short) && bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName) != null)
        {
            short value;
            var val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).FirstValue as string;

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val))
            {
                return ModelBindingResult.SuccessAsync(bindingContext.ModelName, val);
            }
            else if (Int16.TryParse(val, out value) && value >= 0)
            {
                return ModelBindingResult.SuccessAsync(bindingContext.ModelName, value);
            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "The value is invalid.");
            }
        }

        return ModelBindingResult.FailedAsync(bindingContext.ModelName);
    }
}
```

And in cases where the custom value is not specified in the URI it should default to a valid value **(greater than 0)** however it is always defaulting to `0`, even though the controller looks as follows:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(
        [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CustomQueryModelBinder))]short value = 100,
```

Basically value here should be getting set to `100` as its default value when it returns as `null` from the `ModelBinder`.

However this is not happening and it is constantly being returned as `0` which is resulting in `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when trying to do a Get.

We are using **RC1**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `short value = 100` with `short? value = 100` seems to have worked for me. Hooray for nullable types.